# Bash Scripting: How to display output for checking root logins via SSH not allowed?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting, audit

My question is, how do i make the script into a if else statement that it checks if "PermitRootLogin no", it should display the "Vulnerability: No"

and if the "PermitRootLogin yes" it should display as "Vulnerability: Yes"?

Thanks in advance!

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4NJ6.png)

**Script**

```
#!/binbash
      echo "Audit criteria: Root login via SSH are not allowed"
      echo "Vulnerability: Yes"
      echo "Details: See below"
      echo
      echo "Command:"
      echo "grep "^PermitRootLogin" /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
      echo
      echo "Output:"
      grep "^PermitRootLogin" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: What about files containing multiple uses of `PermitRootLogin`, or lines starting with whitespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use variables to store the command output.

This script should do what you need-

```
#!/binbash
      permitrootlogin=`grep "^PermitRootLogin" /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
      if [[ $permitrootlogin == "PermitRootLogin no" ]]
      then 
      isVulnerability="No"
      else
      isVulnerability="Yes"
      fi
      echo "Audit criteria: Root login via SSH are not allowed"
      echo "Vulnerability: $isVulnerability"
      echo "Details: See below"
      echo
      echo "Command:"
      echo "grep "^PermitRootLogin" /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
      echo
      echo "Output:"
      echo $permitrootlogin
```

Comment: While the structure of the test is correct, this isn't a good way to validate your configuration. The file might contain multiple lines matching `^PermitRootLogin`, causing a false positive.